# This form refuses to post with variables

Tags: html, django, forms

```
<form name="myform" action="/submitAssetTag/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
  <input type="hidden" name="gps" id="gps" value="asdasd"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="asset_tag" id="asset_tag" value="asdasdasdasd"/>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit Asset Tag"/>
</form>
```

When I submit this form, the variables are not included in the post. How come!

Comment: Do you mean the `type="hidden"` values aren't sent in the POST, or something else printed from `{% csrf_token %}`?

Comment: the hidden inputs are not included.I have tried using input type="text" as well

Answer (score 0):

It was a combo of not understanding hidden value posts in django, and not watching what i was doing in my view. The values were being posted, but since they are hidden, I wasn't seeing them, and then I was trying to access them wrong in the view.